# Row deleted when it shouldn't be

Tags: sqlite

If I execute the following script in sqlite 3.8.8.3

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;

create table A (
k integer primary key not null
);

create table B (
value text primary key,
k integer references A(k) on delete cascade
);

create table C (
k integer primary key,
value text
);

create trigger C_A before insert on C
begin
insert or ignore into A values(NEW.k);
end;

insert into A values (5);
select * from A;

insert into B values ('asdf', 5);
select * from B;

insert or ignore into A values(5); --just calling this works right
select * from B;

insert or ignore into C values (5, 'qwer'); --this works too
select * from B;  

insert or replace into C values (5, 'qwer'); --this doesn't work
select * from B; --doesn't print anything
```

I get the output

```
5
asdf|5
asdf|5
asdf|5
```

when I'm expecting the output

```
5
asdf|5
asdf|5
asdf|5
asdf|5
```

It seems like the "`or replace`" gets propagated into the trigger, replacing the row in `A`, and deleting the row in `B`.

Is this expected behavior? Am I misunderstanding what this should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

> An [ON CONFLICT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) clause may be specified as part of an [UPDATE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) or [INSERT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) action within the body of the trigger. However if an [ON CONFLICT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) clause is specified as part of the statement causing the trigger to fire, then conflict handling policy of the outer statement is used instead.